# Firebase cloud functions - get parent node while listening for changes on children nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am listening for changes on a particular child node (wallet) for all children in my firebase database.

when any of the wallet nodes across all the values in my database are modified I want to know about it and I want to execute a specific function

[image: screenshot of database]

I require the parent node of the child (wallet) which was just modified

I have tried the following code

```
exports.executeFunction = functions.database.ref('/database/{pushId}/wallet').onWrite((change, context) => {
    //execute my function
}
```

so for example, in the attached screenshot. when the value of wallet is modified in this instance I want to be able to get "rFA2VPdFpSSzdj4JzhmNFogW10x2" as a result as it is the parent node.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`change.before` is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot) object which has a `ref` property.  This is a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) object that you can use to navigate up the nodes to the parent you want.  `change.before.ref.parent` will be a Reference pointing to the parent node you're looking for.

Comment: I've tried this and it is very close to the answer. it returns a reference as follows: " https://<my-database-name>.firebaseio.com/database/rFA2VPdFpSSzdj4JzhmNFogW10x2". is there a way to convert this to just "rFA2VPdFpSSzdj4JzhmNFogW10x2".  I've tried converting this to a string and doing a find and replace to get the uid but to no avail

Comment: Yes, look at the API documentation again for Reference that I linked to.  It has a property called `id` that you can use.

Comment: your suggestions have led me to the answer. thank you!